# How to send a uiview to back of another uiview in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am creating a music application where I am using two uiviews in my main uiview. I want that my one view should be send back of another view.

Comment: What do you mean ?Do you want to make one view overlap the other or do you want to make a flip over transition like in the iPod application?

Comment: Yes, i want to make one view overlap over the other.How is this possible

Comment: This old question needs to be closed as Needs More Focus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[myParentView bringSubviewToFront:myBackView];
```